# Manipulate HTMLCollection with Javacsript

Tags: javascript

JS noob question:

I'm trying to manipulate the HTMLCollection of a Wordpress plugin and I failed for some hours now.
I want to delete the property "baseURI" or set it to null.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    //HTML Collection
    var test = document.getElementsByClassName("post-2968"); 
    
    //manipulate <a> object inside <div>
    test[0].childNodes[0].target="_blank";
    test[0].childNodes[0].href="www.google.com";
    
    //manipulte property of div
    test[0].baseURI = undefined; // also tried "" or null
    
      console.log(test)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the log:
[Console.logg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD1CB.png)

Comment: If you don’t need jQuery for anything else, replace `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){`…`});` by `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {`…`});` or remove it entirely and add a `defer` attribute to your `<script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is written in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI):

> The baseURI --->**read-only**<---- property returns the absolute base URL of a Node.

So I don't think you can change it.

Comment: Oh I didn't read that, thank you.